# What is the Lie algebra of $G=\mathbb{R}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

The question is updated as following.

---

1.
Let $(\Phi,L^2(R))$ be left regular representation of $\mathbb R$ given by
$$
\Phi(g)f(x)=f(x-g).
$$
It is unitary representation of $\mathbb R$.

2.
For $G=\mathbb R$, $c_s(t)=ts,s\in\mathbb R$ is $1$-parameter subgroups in $\mathbb R$.
Note $c_s'(0)=s$. Thus $Lie(\mathbb R)=\{s\in\mathbb R\}$ which is $1$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb R$.

3.
For $f\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, consider the action of $X\in Lie(\mathbb R)$,
$$
\varphi(X)f(x)=\frac{d}{d t}\Phi(t X)f(x)_{t=0}=\frac{d}{d t}f(x-tX)_{t=0}=f'(x)(-X).
$$
Note that $\Phi$ is unitary. The action of $\varphi(X)$ is skew-Hermitian, which implies that $\varphi(X)f(x)$ should be a imaginary multiples of $f'(x)$.

What's wrong?

Comment: You take the tangent space of $\mathbb R$, which is naturally identified with $\mathbb R$ again.  The Lie bracket is trivial (all values zero).